# How to fix checkbox in lightning:recordForm?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, checkbox

I have a problem with checkboxes when using lightning:recordForm.
My code:

```
 <lightning:recordForm objectApiName="Opportunity" recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                              mode="view" fields="{!v.LeadHistory}" columns="2"
                              onload="{!c.handleOnLoad}" onsuccess="{!c.handleOnSuccess}"
                              onsubmit="{!v.handleOnSubmit}"/>
```

[image]

As u can see each checkbox is display in 3 lines. I would like that edit button would be in the same line. 
Every other field from my object renders fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Styling .inpitFieldWidth by adding width haven't worked for me.
I added:

```
.THIS .slds-form-element__static{
display: inline-block;}
```

styly into my component and it has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add Style to your Component. below i am posting example code. which worked for me.

```
.THIS .inputFieldWidth {
width:85%;
}
```

Thanks